# The textContent or innerText changes for like milliseconds then goes back as it was

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

**My html code**

```
<form id="form">
      <input type="text" class="search" id="search">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">

      <ul><li id="first"></li></ul>
</form>
```

**My Javascript code**

```
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function() {Search()};

var itemListVal = "";

isChanged = false;

function Search() {
    let inputValue = document.getElementById("search").value;
    document.querySelector("#first").innerText = inputValue;
    
    itemListVal = inputValue;
    isChanged = true;
}
```

I was trying to make the item list which I was gonna make as a search history (I am new to frontend developing so I am not trying to storing yet ig) to change as the last searched thing aka the last submitted but It only changes for a really little bit of time and goes back as it is

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the form from submitting to the server and reloading the page?

Comment: Submit Buttons Submit Forms. You don't cancel the form submission....The form submits and reloads the page.

Comment: @David I am not trying to reload the page ig, and I didn't understand what you meant by submitting to the server, thanks though